# NetGear WNR1000v2h2

Tags: сеть, роутер, l2tp

Являюсь обладателем NetGear WNR1000v2h2. Сегодня были проблемы с сетью, а билайн как обычно недоступен. Решил я поставить актуальную прошивку, которую я нашел на официальном [сайте](http://spb.beeline.ru)  версии 1.1.2.50. Беда в том, что во всех версиях, кроме 1.0.1.20/22, нет поддержки нужного мне L2TP. Если кто знает где достать - помогите!

Answer (score 0):

Нашел другую версию, надеюсь, будет стабильна
http://ftp.ufanet.ru/pub/firmware/Netgear/WNR1000v2/